# Dynamic page include - any better ways to do it?

Tags: php

I wrote simple menu for my web game

Every page is accessed like this:

```
http/localhost/index.php?page=PAGENAME
```

This is how my include system works now:

```
switch($page) {


 case "login":
        include "login.php";
        break;

 //Other 110 cases...

 case "authors":
       include "authors.php";
       break;

}
```

As you can see it's not dynamical, every page must be added to switch menu. It was working well, but after some time my code got larger and larger. Now this switch contains almost 125 cases and it's an PITA to maintain.

My question - is there better, safe  and dynamical way to do it?

I know i can do something like this:

```
include $page.".php";
```

But it's very insecure and i don't want to do it.

Comment: It might be time to consider implementing a framework, which will handle this sort of routing more gracefully.

Comment: why not just link to the files directly? `/login.php` and `/authors.php` is just as easy to do as a single container file.

Comment: If the files name is always the same as the variable, why not check if the file with the name exists and then include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a Framework to handle your URLs and want to conserve urls just like this, then what I suggest in this case is to use the following:

```
$pages = array(
    'login',
    'authors',
    //...
);
if(in_array($page, $pages))
    include $page .'.php';
else
    include 'not_found.php';
```

You can even do better and generate the `$pages` array dynamically reading the PHP files in your directory.

Comment: Neat, thank you! Project is so big that rewriting it to framework would take months.